# How to iterate through every member of a guild and give them a role. JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

So I want to give everyone without access to control time the role Muted I tried implementing the following code but the console only give the bot and my name as output

```
if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("The World!")) {
            Role e = findRole(event.getMember(), "Time");
            if (e.equals(null)) return;
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("https://tenor.com/view/dio-the-world-power-charge-gif-13331683").queue();
            Role role = event.getGuild().getRolesByName("Muted", false).get(0);
            java.util.List<Member> users = guild.getMembers();
            for (Member member :users) {
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(member));
                Role e1 = findRole(member, "Time");
                System.out.println(member+String.valueOf(e1));
                if (e1.equals(null)){
                    guild.addRoleToMember(member, role).queue();
                    System.out.println(member+" "+e1);
                }
                    
                }
        }
```

MB:Prime(U:Prime(737242975335350285) / G:Chaos Reloaded(617029996921487360))
MB:Prime(U:Prime(737242975335350285) / G:Chaos Reloaded(617029996921487360))R:Time(760807424810156032)
MB:mZe(U:mZe(680322904449220660) / G:Chaos Reloaded(617029996921487360))
MB:mZe(U:mZe(680322904449220660) / G:Chaos Reloaded(617029996921487360))null

Comment: No.. I still shows me and the bot. I've turned it on on Dev Portal and code is
JDABuilder.createDefault(token).addEventListeners(new Main()).setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
        .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
        .build();

And the old code for method

Comment: You're still missing something, I suggest you read the answer I posted there.